# can't find definition of FT_LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT and FT_LOAD_NO_HINTING?

Tags: opencascade

when I compile Visualization folder, that is the error in Font_FTFont.cxx
I made the error go away by changing

```
#ifdef HAVE_FREETYPE
  #include <ft2build.h>
  #include FT_FREETYPE_H
#endif
// changed to 
#ifndef HAVE_FREETYPE
  #include <ft2build.h>
  #include FT_FREETYPE_H
#endif
```

I don't know how to fix the error and whether my change has major hidden issues?